# Jquery Function Hangs

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-bubbling, event-delegation

I am using a plugin called h5validate. I have found the only way to initiate this plugin is by clicking out of (bluring) the field i want to validate, so my logic is to setup a function which does this for me when i click (as it happens) a next button; I have tried calling the validate function directly but it doesn't work.

Anyway my question is:

**1. This function hangs the browser for ~3seconds, why?**

```
$(document).on('click', '.tab', function () {
$this = $(this);
    if( $this.is('#tab1') )     { $('.tab-content-first .row .cell input:not(#ImageLocation)').blur(); }
    if( $this.is('#tab2') )     { $('.tab-content-1 .row .cell input:not(#ImageLocation)').blur(); }
    if( $this.is('#tab3') )     { $('.tab-content-2 .row .cell input:not(#ImageLocation)').blur(); }
    if( $this.is('#tab4') )     { $('.tab-content-3 .row .cell input:not(#ImageLocation)').blur(); }
    if( $this.is('#tab5') )     { $('.tab-content-4 .row .cell input:not(#ImageLocation)').blur(); }
    if( $this.is('#tab6') )     { $('.tab-content-5 .row .cell input:not(#ImageLocation)').blur(); }
});
```

**Edit:** 
I have cashed $('this'); as an object as suggested.

I've decided it's probably bubbling up, the docs recommend i stoppropagation(), but that doesn't work, i'm using delegation as i'm calling this through ajax could that be why stoppropagation() doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

First: `$(this)` should be cached. The rest of `$()` can be also cached, and before function.

Second: use strategy pattern

Comment: interesting, ill give it ago.

Comment: If still there is a problem give more code or link to app, becouse I can't do nothing more with it :)

Comment: So that shouldn't be locking up just on it own?

Comment: Add more code, because this don't tell us much about bubbling. If you could copy it to jsfiddle or codepen with the same behaviour (3s hanging) it'd be great.